# Get dynamically loaded html in java

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, dhtml

I need to grab the whole HTML from a web page included dynamically generated HTML. Is it possible in JAVA or in PHP?

When I Inspect element with firebug it shows whole HTML. but when I use java I get only static HTML file.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: No. Suppose you are loading data in webpage using ajax and dynamically generating html tags and inserting it in your static html file. Now I want to read the whole html file(static + dynamically loaded)

Comment: The problem is that you aren't interpreting the javascript. So you need some way of retrieving the js files (or the js script tags) and executing them.

Comment: @xp500 would you please help me how can I do this in Java or PHP?

Comment: Webpage is generating some tags dynamically so I want to grab them and parse them.

Comment: You make a call to a page , you get back content that needs to be run by your local javascript engine and that then makes more content that you wish to capture.  You need to look at scrappers and you should look to nodeJS, Perl, etc.. This not a trivial task to do.

Comment: another option would be to send the html of the current page state to java through an ajax call. I don't know if that's the kind of answer youre looking for though.